# Getting started with Omnet++, Veins, and Sumo

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am having trouble getting Omnet++, Veins, and Sumo to work together.  I am progressing through this [tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) to get started. I am currently on the Final Step and I am getting some error that I was hoping someone had some insight on.

I am installing Omnet++, Veins, and Sumo on a virtual machine in Centos 7.  I have been through the installation of these three programs twice and I believe I have correctly completed all the steps, although I am pretty new to linux and could have made a mistake.

Here is a link to a screen shot from Omnet when I run the example code from the Final Step:  [image: omnet error]

The library it failed to load is libosg.so.130.  This looks like an Open Scene Graph library.  I was getting a very similar error yesterday having to do with a osgEarth library.  I was able to get around this by disabling selinux, which was blocking some shared libraries from being accessed.  I tried the same solution with libosg with no avail.  Is there a different antivirus/firewall on Centos that I should turn off?  Or is there another idea I should look into?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

EDIT, SOLUTION:  I fixed the error by adding the folder /usr/local/lib64 to my path by editing the bashrc with gedit ~/.bashrc and adding "export PATH=$HOME/omnetpp-5.1.1/bin:$PATH:/path_to_folder" to the bottom of the document.

Comment: can you run any of the OMNeT++ example simulations (for example, the TicToc tutorial)?

Comment: If you don't need OSG and OSG Earth, you can disable them in the configure.user file of your OMNeT installation, rerun ./configure, make cleanall, and finally another run of make to compile OMNeT without OSG support.

Comment: @ChristophSommer I am able to run the TicToc like a charm.

Comment: @MichaelKrische I do need OSG and OSGEarth unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I was able to locate the libraries in /usr/local/lib64 and move them to /usr/lib64 which fixed the problem.  I would love to know how to just point omnet so it knows to check /usr/local/lib64 though, it feels sloppy the way I fixed this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That is really weird. Have you moved OMNeT++ between compiling it and running the simulation? Would re-recompiling OMNeT++ help?

Comment: @ChristophSommer Thanks for your advice on this.  My issue was that I am a noob with paths in Linux.  I have resolved the issue, and many others, through some research about PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Once these were set correctly I was able to get the simulator up and running.  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem! If you can, it would be great if you could add an answer to your question that details the steps you took. This way, if anybody experiences a similar problem, they can easily find the solution.